# A question on a Macaulay2 computation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, projective-geometry, computer-algebra, ideals

I have an ideal $I$ generated by quadratic and cubic homogeneous polynomials in $10$ variables.

Macaulay2 tells me that $I$ defines an irreducible variety $X$ of dimension $5$ and degree $10$ in $\mathbb{P}^9$, and that $I$ is not radical.

When I ask for the primary decomposition of $I$ Macaulay2 gives me two ideals $I_0,I_1$. He says that $I_0$ is radical and defines an irreducible variety of dimension $5$ and degree $10$, while $I_1$ is not radical and defines a variety of dimension $-1$. Indeed, when I ask for the radical of $I_1$ Macaulay2 gives me the ideal generated by all the homogeneous coordinates of $\mathbb{P}^9$ thus corresponding to the empty set. This last fact is really confusing me.

What is then the meaning of $I_1$ in the primary decomposition of $I$?

Thank you very much in advance.

Here are the ideals I am considering

```
P9 = QQ[a00,a01,a02,a03,a11,a12,a13,a22,a23,a33]

F0 = a00*a12-a01*a02+a01*a13-a03*a11

F1 = a00*a23+a01*a33-a02*a03-a03*a13

F2 = a01*a22-a02*a12+a11*a23-a12*a13

F3 = a02*a23-a03*a22+a12*a33-a13*a23

F4 = a00*a22-a02^2-a11*a33+a13^2

J = ideal(F0,F1,F2,F3,F4)

M = matrix{{a00,a01,a02,a03},{a01,a11,a12,a13},{a02,a12,a22,a23},{a03,a13,a23,a33}}

I = J + minors(3,M)

L = primaryDecomposition(I)

X = variety L_0

Y = variety L_1

dim(X)

dim(Y)
```

Comment: Just to have it available:  https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.12/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_primary_spdecomposition.html .

Comment: In terms of the definition, it seems to me that we would expect $I = I_0 \cap I_1$ (which I think we can't judge from the information given) and $\sqrt{I_0} \ne \sqrt{I_1}$ (which is the case in your computation).  I think that there is no expectation that $I_1$ itself be radical.

Comment: I posted the ideals I am considering. What is really unclear to me is the difference between the variety defined by $I$ and the variety defined by $L_0$.

Comment: When you post code, please make sure to format it as code (either by manually adding 4 spaces at the beginning of each line, or by using the format-as-code button in the GUI).  Otherwise, Markdown gets at it and makes a mess.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: I am sorry. Next time I will do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Commutative algebra is NOT the same as algebraic geometry, especially projective algebraic geometry.

The variety in $\mathbb{P}^9$ defined by $I$ and the variety in $\mathbb{P}^9$ defined by $I_0$ are the same variety.

If you were to work in $\mathbb{A}^{10}$, then $I$ and $I_0$ would define different affine schemes; the scheme defined by $I$ has some extra fatness at the origin, but since the origin is not part of projective space, you don't see this difference in $\mathbb{P}^9$.

EDIT: The relevant bit of Hartshorne is Exercise II.5.10

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I suspected that the varieties defined by $I$ and $I_0$ had to coincide. Anyway I am still confused about $I$ not being radical. Can we have a non radical ideal $I$ such that $I$ and $r(I)$ define the same scheme? This seems to be the case. Could you elaborate a bit more on the facr that $I$ and $I_0$ define the same scheme in $\mathbb{P}^9$?

Comment: Your question is, I think, exactly @AlexanderWoo’s point:  a non-radical ideal and its radical will *always* define the same variety, but *never* the same scheme.  It may help to simplify your picture to $I = (x^2)$; then the *variety* determined by $I$ is the single point $\{0\}$ in affine space, but the *scheme* determined by $I$ is a *doubled* point $\{0\}$.  You can see the difference, for example, by finding that the tangent space to the scheme at its sole point is 1-dimensional.

Comment: No I think that Alexander Woo is claiming that the ideal $I$ and its radical define the same scheme in $\mathbb{P}^9$ but different schemes in $\mathbb{A}^{10}$.

Comment: @user125056, you are [right](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375347/a-question-on-a-macaulay2-computation/375361#comment951606_375361).  Sorry!

Comment: @user125056: You should look at Exercise II.5.10 in Hartshorne for more details.